# Speeding up Loading of Pandas Sparse DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, concatenation, sparse-matrix

I have a large pickled Sparse DataFrame that I generated, but since it was too big to hold in memory, I had to incrementally append as it was generated, as follows:

```
with open(data.pickle, 'ab') as output:
    pickle.dump(df.to_sparse(), output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Then in order to read the file back I do the following:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([]).to_sparse()
with open(data.pickle, 'rb') as pickle_file:
    try:
        while True:
            test =  pickle.load(pickle_file)
            df_2 = pd.concat([df_2, test], ignore_index= True)
    except EOFError:
        pass
```

Given the size of this file(20 GB), this method works, but obviously takes a really really long time. Is it possible to parallelize the pickle.load/pd.concat steps for quicker loading time? Or are there any other suggestions for speeding this process up, specifically on the loading part of the code.

Note: The generation step is done on a computer with significantly less resources, so that's why the load step, which is done on a more powerful machine, can hold the DF in memory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't concat in a loop! This is a [note](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) in the docs, maybe should be a warning

```
df_list = []
with open(data.pickle, 'rb') as pickle_file:
    try:
        while True:
            test =  pickle.load(pickle_file)
            df_list.append(test)
    except EOFError:
        pass

df_2 = pd.concat(df_list), ignore_index= True)
```

You are making a copy of the frame **EACH TIME** in your loop now, and it is growing, so this is not efficient at all.

The idiom is to append to a list, then do a single concat all at the end.

Furthermore, you are going to be much better off writing to an `HDF5` file in the data generation. Which is faster, and compressible. You can usually get away with writing a full df, unless its extremely sparse when you turn on compression.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this tomorrow morning! The DataFrame is extremely sparse, and I ran into memory issues with the DataFrame in dense format with HDF5. Is there a way to write a sparse DF in HDF5? Thanks :)

Comment: you can write a sparse frame with fixed format (table format is not implemented )

Comment: you cannot append to a single mode, but you could simply write nodes as needed and just append them when u read it out